# Ignore Excel Files That Are Password Protected

Tags: excel, vba

I am iterating a directory full of .xlsx files.  I am using VBA to open them and resize a few columns.  Some of them are asking for a password, that I do not know, so I just want to skip these files and move onto the next.  How in VBA can this be achieved?  I tried the below but no such luck.

```
Set openedBook = Workbooks.Open(File, IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended:=True)
```

[image]

Here is an image of the error I get -- how can I either ignore the workbook completely or VBA to click "Cancel" on the prompt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try passing a (known invalid) password and use error handling to ignore the failure

Something like this

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim openedBook  As Workbook
    Dim sFile As String

    sFile = "C:\Your\File\Name.xlsx"

    Set openedBook = Nothing ' in case openedBook was previously set to somthing

    On Error Resume Next
    Set openedBook = Workbooks.Open( _
      FileName:=sFile, _
      IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended:=True, _
      Password:="!")

    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not openedBook Is Nothing Then
        ' do your stuff
    Else
        ' For demo purposes only
        MsgBox "File " & sFile & " is password protected"
    End If

End Sub
```